# List with "adjective, adverb adjective noun"

Tags: lists

I was taught that co-ordinate adjective lists can be used under the format **adjective, adjective noun**. However, I was wondering if a co-ordinate list can be used under the structure **adjective, adverb adjective noun**.

Example:

> The Poincaré conjecture is a **challenging, outwardly unsolvable** problem.

Answer (score 1):

The adverb isn't a member of the coordinated list. The adverb modifies one of the adjectives, and that adjective phrase still functions as an adjective in that list, so yes, the grammar and meaning are still good.

Comment: So you mean that the adverb+adjective constitute something called an adjectival phrase that operates as the second adjective in the list? Thanks.

Comment: @goalie It's an "**adjective** phrase because it has an actual adjective as the head. An "**adjectival** phrase" is any phrase that functions as an adjective, regardless of whether it has an adjective as its head.